# Does nginx supports websocket with binary

Tags: nginx, websocket, binary-data

I'm testing nginx by sending binary data(byte[]) using websocket connection and it doesn't work correctly. I used the following settings.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
         server_name oracleapps.veeralab.com;
        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_read_timeout 84600s;
                proxy_send_timeout 84600s;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using nginx 1.4 and above?

Comment: Yes.I'm using latest one.